# create pie charts with facet wrap?

Tags: r, pie-chart, facet-wrap

I manage to create a dataframe as shown but I dont know how to create faceted pie charts out of it. Can someone show me how? Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT3pf.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [faceted piechart with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592789/faceted-piechart-with-ggplot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to show, so you could do something like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(rideable_type = c("classic_bike", "classic_bike", "docked_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike"),
                 member_causal = c("causal", "member", "causal", "causal", "member"),
                 number_of_bikes = c(1313878, 2013712, 308241, 1048194, 1250025),
                 total = c(2670303, 3263737, 2670303, 2670303, 3263737),
                 freq = c(49.2, 61.6, 11.5, 39.2, 38.3))


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(1), fill=factor(rideable_type))) + 
  facet_wrap(~member_causal) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1,position = "fill") + 
  coord_polar(theta="y") +
  labs(fill = "rideable type", x = "", y = "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks a lot! i have one more question ^_^ can you show me how to put percentage label on it?